# Is it possible to know from apt if the package was installed explicitly or as a dependency of another package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Let's say there are `A`, `B` and `C` package.

`A` and `C` were installed manually with `apt-get install`, and `B` is a dependency of `A` and was installed by `apt` automatically.

Is it possible to know that with some `apt-*` or `dpkg` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check whether a package was installed manually by displaying the list of all automatically installed packages with `apt-mark showauto`.

```
apt-mark showauto | grep -x B
```

`aptitude -v why B` shows which packages depend on B. Sticking with aptitude, `aptitude version B` displays an `A` in the third column if B is marked as automatically installed.

`apt-cache show A` or `dpkg -s A` (if A is installed) shows A's dependencies. `apt-cache rdepends B` shows what depends on B.

Comment: Please explain why you suggest `grep -x`? If I run `apt-mark showauto | grep -x geany`, I get the prompt back. If I run `apt-mark showauto | grep geany`, I get `geany-common` and 
`geany-plugins-common`. Thanks!

Comment: @DKBose `grep -x` searches for the exact package name. If you remove `-x`, you get a match for any package name containing the argument as a substring. If `apt-mark showauto | grep -x geany` shows nothing, it means that either `geany` is not installed or it's marked as manually installed.