# When an apt package is flagged as "automatically installed", is it possible to view which package triggered the installation?

Tags: apt, package-management

When `apt` lists an automatically-installed package that I don't recognize, I'd sometimes like to know which manually-installed package originally triggered the installation. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean something like the output of `apt list --installed | grep -i gtk3`?

Comment: And have you looked at `apt rdepends package_name` for clues? If it's a recently installed application, you could look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` or the archived version to see what else was installed when you installed the "primary" package.

Comment: @DKBose `apt list --installed` only seems to indicate that a package was automatically installed, but (as far as I can tell) doesn't show what actually caused the automatic installation. `history.log` seems like exactly what I needed though, thank you! Could you post as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Your question has probably been asked and answered before. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355070/is-it-possible-to-know-from-apt-if-the-package-was-installed-explicitly-or-as-a?rq=1). I suggest you close your question as a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a example of script that use 2 commands to scan all packages information , to identify manual packages that installation of your packages .

`apt list -installed`

```
=> provide a list of package and you can see if the package was installed automaticaly
```

`apt-cache rdepends --installed PACKAGE`

=> provide a list currently installed that depends on PACKAGE

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo help:
    echo  $0    PACKAGE
    echo
    echo find packages that was manual installed that install PACKAGE as a dependency
    echo
    exit 1
fi
ROOT_PKG="$1";
echo "package $ROOT_PKG" ;
FG=$(mktemp);
apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | grep automatic > $FG;
ALREADY_DISPLAY=":"
ALREADY_SCAN=":"
while [ -n "$ROOT_PKG" ];
do
      for P in $ROOT_PKG;
      do
              ROOT_PKG="";
              for RDP in $( apt-cache rdepends --installed $P | sed '0,/^Reverse Depends:/  d;' );
              do
                      RDP=$(echo "$RDP" | sed 's/^|//' ) ;
                      if ( grep -q "^${RDP}/"  $FG );
                      then
                              if ( ! ( echo "$ALREADY_SCAN" | grep -q ":$RDP" ) )
                              then
                                  ROOT_PKG="$ROOT_PKG $RDP";
                                  ALREADY_SCAN="$ALREADY_SCAN:$RDP"
                              fi
                      else
                              if ( ! ( echo "$ALREADY_DISPLAY" | grep -q ":$RDP" ) )
                              then
                                 echo " was needed by $RDP";
                                 ALREADY_DISPLAY="$ALREADY_DISPLAY:$RDP"
                              fi
                      fi;
              done;
      done;
done;
```